# Normalization and patient effect

Tags: r, machine-learning, normalization

I have a very simple question but I don't really have answer myself... I have a set of data like this :

```r
structure(list(PatientID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"P5", "P6"), LesionResponse = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), pyrad_tum_original_shape_LeastAxisLength = c(19.7842995242803, 
    15.0703960571122, 21.0652247652897, 11.804125918871, 27.3980336338908, 
    17.0584330264122, 4.90406343942677, 4.78480430022189, 6.2170232078547, 
    5.96309532740722, 5.30141540007441), pyrad_tum_original_shape_Sphericity = c(0.652056853392657, 
    0.773719977240238, 0.723869070051882, 0.715122964970338, 
    0.70796498824535, 0.811937882810929, 0.836458991713367, 0.863337931630415, 
    0.851654860256904, 0.746212862162174), pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_firstorder_Skewness = c(0.367453961973625, 
    0.117673346718817, 0.0992025164349288, -0.174029385779302, 
    -0.863570016875989, -0.8482193060411, -0.425424618080682, 
    -0.492420174157913, 0.0105111292451967, 0.249865833210199), pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_glcm_Contrast = c(0.376932105256115, 
    0.54885738172596, 0.267158344601612, 2.90094719958076, 0.322424096161189, 
    0.221356030145403, 1.90012334870722, 0.971638740404501, 0.31547550396399, 
    0.653999340294952), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_GrayLevelNonUniformityNormalized = c(0.154973213866752, 
    0.176128379241556, 0.171129002059539, 0.218343919352019, 
    0.345985943932352, 0.164905080489496, 0.104536489151874, 
    0.1280276816609, 0.137912385073012, 0.133420904484894), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaEmphasis = c(27390.2818110851, 
    11327.7931034483, 51566.7948885976, 7261.68702290076, 340383.536555142, 
    22724.7792207792, 45.974358974359, 142.588235294118, 266.744186046512, 
    1073.45205479452), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaLowGrayLevelEmphasis = c(677.011907073653, 
    275.281153810458, 582.131636238695, 173.747506476692, 6140.73990175018, 
    558.277670638306, 1.81042257642817, 4.55724031114589, 6.51794350173746, 
    19.144924585586), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_SizeZoneNonUniformityNormalized = c(0.411899490603372, 
    0.339216399209913, 0.425584323452468, 0.355165782879786, 
    0.294934042125209, 0.339208410636982, 0.351742274819198, 
    0.394463667820069, 0.360735532720389, 0.36911240382811)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

All I want is to normalize the datas, but I have to take into account the "patient-centre effect", I'll explain myself : I know how to normalize, but I don't find any function on R to normalize and take into account this bias ... to resume, I know how to normalize by columns, but not by columns and by rows ...

Comment: Can you be clear on what your definition of "normalize" is here? Do you mean rescale so it has a mean 0 and standard deviation of 1? It's not clear exactly what you mean by the "patient-care effect". It sounds like you have more questions about statistical modeling rather than programming. You should probably get data analysis advice first from [stats.se].

Comment: In fact, I'm wondering if there is a possibility to normalize and take into account the fact that many rows are dependent between each others !

Comment: As the comment by @MrFlick suggests, in order to get a useful answer, it would be helpful if you could explain what you mean by "normalize".  Also, what it would mean to normalize according to "patient-centre effect".  What variable captures this effect ?  What properties would the normalized output have ?